# PHP LDAP search/list filter problem - logical NOT

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm running an ldap_list with this filter:

```
"(&(givenname=*)(objectClass=User)(!department=Executive))"
```

and I get zero results and this warning in the PHP log:

> ldap_get_entries(): supplied argument is not a valid ldap result resource...

If I remove the NOT operator for *department* and run it:

```
"(&(givenname=*)(objectClass=User)(department=Executive))"
```

I get the exact results I'm expecting and no warning.  Since I get good results with the latter filter, I can only assume my ldap connection, base_DN, and attributes are correct.  I've run both filters in Active Directory Users and Computers via the Management Console and both run perfectly so I can assume the filter is correct.  Just for grins I tried ldap_search instead of ldap_list and got the same results.  Any ideas?

Oh, I'm running PHP 5.2.14 on IIS 7.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the operator outside the parentheses

```
(!(department=Executive))
```